# php/mysql search table with unknown number of filters

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, search

I've seen on many shopping websites they have search filters on the side, and you can add any number of filters and it researches the data showing only the data that matches all of the filter queries.

As an example, if you go to ebay and look for a computer, you can filter by various specs of the computer to narrow the results.

The problem I'm having is working out how to do this for a table that has so many fields that a user may search by.

I have a table of Properties that I want to search by any number of parameters e.g. rent, location, etc.

I could create search queries for each possible option e.g. `searchByAddress($array)`, `searchByAddressAndRent($array)`, etc. but that's clearly not feasible.

Another way I could create separate queries for each field, then trigger separate search queries for each parameter i.e. `searchByRent($array)`, `searchByAddress($array)` and allow the PHP application to compute which fields are common in all resulting arrays using [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php).

But I was wondering, there must be a proper technique in achieving this. This question is a bit long-winded and I couldn't find any tutorials on it from googling.

So my question is, what's the "right" method/technique of searching a database table with various search-filters?

Comment: If you have taken the time to read the question and down-voted, please comment on what I should do to improve the question. Thanks.

Comment: I believe they are implementing some sort of [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model). It has its disadvantages too. See [How to structure a large form application?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17745114) to read some about it on this site.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I can't work out in my head how having an EAV structure helps to search a single entity for matching its fields to a variable number of values? Is it because there is one huge table in the EAV model with 'attribute' and 'value' columns so that you just have to search 'attribute' to match various values?

Comment: @Script47 That was a bit random. I'm actually using PDO, but I don't see how that's related to my question.

Comment: @Ozzy, You're right, sorry, under your question tag it said "mysql" my bad, will remove the comment. **Removed**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a class representing the property table, you can define a static array in the class detailing each field name and corresponding data type.

On the front end, each search field should correspond to the column name in the database, so the $_REQUEST array keys will match the column names.

After this, iterate through your search array, checking each variable exists in your class field definition array, and add it onto the search query.

Below is a very simplified example class which will hopefully give you the idea.

```
class Property () {

    // search parameters come from $values_array
    // each search field should correspond to the $field_definitions key
    public function search($values_array = null) {

        // populate the values array. Using this method meads you can pass an array directly
        // into the search function, or you can rely on the $_REQUEST
        $values_array = self::getValuesArray($values_array);

        // setup the initial query
        $query = "SELECT * FROM properties";
        // set our initial join string
        $join = "WHERE";

        // loop each of our search values
        foreach ($values_array as $field=>$value) {
            // check the search key exists in our table definition and it's not empty
            if (array_key_exists($field_definitions, self::$fields) && !empty($value)) {
                // switch the datatype for the field so we can set the appropriate query string
                switch (self::$field_definitions[$field]) {

                    case 'int':
                        $query .= "$join $field = {$value} ";
                        $join = "AND";
                        break;

                    default:
                        $query .= "$join $field = '%{$value}%' ";
                        $join = "AND";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        // now execute the query... 
        $results = mysql_query($query);

        // do something to process the results and then return

        return $results;
    }

    // basic function to grab our values from $_REQUEST if passed an empty array
    private function getValuesArray($values_array = null) {

        $values_array = (!empty($values_array)) ? $values_array : $_REQUEST;
        return $values_array;
    }

    // variable containing all available fields in table and corresponding datatype
    public static $field_definitions = 
        array(  'number'=>'int',
            'street'=>'string',
            'locality'=>'string',
            'townland'=>'string',
            'town'=>'string',
            'postcode'=>'string'
        );
}
```

Comment: Right so I dynamically build the SQL query, got it! I also wondered how to handle the field definitions because this is sometimes a problem with PDO if the `int`'s aren't caste to `int` so really great answer, thank you :).